# How to type a closure?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, closures, typescript-generics

[Todos.tsx](https://github.com/manifet/todos/blob/master/src/components/TodoItem.tsx)

```
import React, {useState, useCallback} from "react";
import {TransitionGroup, CSSTransition} from "react-transition-group";
import {v4 as uuid} from "uuid";

import {ITodoEventsArgs, TodoEvents, ITodoItem} from "../utils";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import AddTodo from "./AddTodo";

interface TodosProps {
    initialTodos: ITodoItem[]
}

const Todos = ({initialTodos}: TodosProps) => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState<ITodoItem[]>(initialTodos)

    const updateTodos = (newTodos: ITodoItem[]) => {
        localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(newTodos))
        setTodos(newTodos)
    }

    const todoTools = <K extends keyof ITodoEventsArgs>(event: K, todoId?: ITodoItem["id"]) => {
        let newTodos: ITodoItem[] = [];

        // An object with all actions. Here we type functions based on arguments and ITodoTools keys.
        const allActions: { [K in keyof ITodoEventsArgs]: (...args: ITodoEventsArgs[K]) => void } = {
            [TodoEvents.Add]: (title) => {
                if (title.trim() !== '') {
                    newTodos.push({id: uuid(), completed: false, title: title})
                }
            },
            [TodoEvents.Complete]: () => {
                const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todoId)
                newTodos[todoIndex].completed = !newTodos[todoIndex].completed
            },
            [TodoEvents.Delete]: () => {
                const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todoId)
                newTodos.splice(todoIndex, 1)
            },
            [TodoEvents.Edit]: (newTitle) => {
                const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todoId)
                newTodos[todoIndex].title = newTitle
            }
        }

        // Here we get the action we need
        const action = allActions[event]

        // Here we return a function with the actions we need,
        // but if we pass it to the child component via props,
        // then we need to type it again in as is done in TodoItem.tsx
        return (...args: ITodoEventsArgs[K]) => {
            newTodos = [...todos]
            action(...args)
            updateTodos(newTodos)
        }
    }

    const filterTodos = useCallback((completed: boolean) => todos.map(item => {
            const itemId = item.id
            return completed === item.completed ?
                <CSSTransition classNames="todo" timeout={300} key={itemId}>
                    <TodoItem deleteTodo={todoTools(TodoEvents.Delete, itemId)}
                              completeTodo={todoTools(TodoEvents.Complete, itemId)}
                              editTodo={todoTools(TodoEvents.Edit, itemId)}
                              todoItem={item}
                    />
                </CSSTransition> :
                null
        }

    ), [todos])
...
}
```

So, in each action on the todos, we copy the array and update the state. I had an idea to combine these actions into one function to do something like redux.

### How to type the `todoTools` function while avoiding repetition, unreadable code, and retaining reusability?

My main problem is how to type the `todoTools` function. According to my idea, the function takes an `event` and, based on it, returns a function whose arguments are typed exactly the same as in `allActions[event]`. In my example, I made a working function, based on [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) answer, but there are a few problems:

Interfaces in utils.ts are defined through the keys of `TodoEvents`. But what if I need to add a new key to `TodoEvents`? I'll have to change two interfaces, and the compiler won't throw an error if I don't. And the very definition of the `ITodoEvents` interface is a repetition of the typing of `allActions`

[utils.ts](https://github.com/manifet/todos/blob/master/src/utils.ts)

```
export interface ITodoItem {
    completed: boolean,
    title: string,
    id: string
}

export enum TodoEvents {
    Add,
    Complete,
    Delete,
    Edit
}

export interface ITodoEventsArgs {
    [TodoEvents.Add]: [title: ITodoItem["title"]],
    [TodoEvents.Complete]: [],
    [TodoEvents.Delete]: [],
    [TodoEvents.Edit]: [newTitle: ITodoItem["title"]]
}

export interface ITodoEvents {
    [TodoEvents.Add]: (...args:ITodoEventsArgs[TodoEvents.Add]) => void,
    [TodoEvents.Complete]: (...args:ITodoEventsArgs[TodoEvents.Complete]) => void,
    [TodoEvents.Delete]: (...args:ITodoEventsArgs[TodoEvents.Delete]) => void,
    [TodoEvents.Edit]: (...args:ITodoEventsArgs[TodoEvents.Edit]) => void
}
```

What do I want? I want to type a function through one `ITodoEvents` interface. I would like to do something like this:

```
const todoTools = <K extends keyof ITodoEvents>(event: K, todoId?: ITodoItem["id"]) => {
        let newTodos: ITodoItem[] = [];

        const allActions: ITodoEvents = {
            [TodoEvents.Add]: (title) => {
                if (title.trim() !== '') {
                    newTodos.push({id: uuid(), completed: false, title: title})
                }
            },
            [TodoEvents.Complete]: () => {
                const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todoId)
                newTodos[todoIndex].completed = !newTodos[todoIndex].completed
            },
            [TodoEvents.Delete]: () => {
                const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todoId)
                newTodos.splice(todoIndex, 1)
            },
            [TodoEvents.Edit]: (newTitle) => {
                const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todoId)
                newTodos[todoIndex].title = newTitle
            }
        }

        const action = allActions[event]

        const resultFunc: ITodoEvents[K] = (...args) => {
            newTodos = [...todos]
            action(...args)
            updateTodos(newTodos)
        }

        return resultFunc
    }
```

But this code throws two errors:

```
Rest parameter 'args' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.

A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.
```

[Repository](https://github.com/manifet/todos) with my todo app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for [ask].  You should consider [edit]ing your post to [ask a *single* main question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jcalz I described what the problem is in the second paragraph under the heading. It is logical to assume that I do not know the solution, but after describing the problems, I added a code example that I would like to see

Comment: If you can provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a single file in a standalone IDE, I might be able to investigate.  Or, barring that, a link to a properly configured web IDE project that shows what's happening.  I'm afraid I can't commit to installing a github repo in my local environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it like the following by removing `ITodoEventsArgs` entirely.

```js
export interface ITodoEvents {
    [TodoEvents.Add]: (title: ITodoItem["title"]) => void,
    [TodoEvents.Complete]: () => void,
    [TodoEvents.Delete]: () => void,
    [TodoEvents.Edit]: (newTitle: ITodoItem["title"]) => void
}
```

And then force the result of `todoTools` function to be `ITodoEvents[K]` and use `any` type for the arguments and the result itself. `any` is needed because `args` has all the type possibilities at the same time (a union of them). Otherwise, you'd need to use `switch(event)` and return a function wrapper for every event that exists.

```js
    const todoTools = <K extends keyof ITodoEvents>(event: K, todoId?: ITodoItem["id"]): ITodoEvents[K] => {
        let newTodos: ITodoItem[] = [];

        const allActions: ITodoEvents = {
            [TodoEvents.Add]: (title) => {
                if (title.trim() !== '') {
                    newTodos.push({id: uuid(), completed: false, title: title})
                }
            },
            [TodoEvents.Complete]: () => {
                const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todoId)
                newTodos[todoIndex].completed = !newTodos[todoIndex].completed
            },
            [TodoEvents.Delete]: () => {
                const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todoId)
                newTodos.splice(todoIndex, 1)
            },
            [TodoEvents.Edit]: (newTitle) => {
                const todoIndex = todos.findIndex(item => item.id === todoId)
                newTodos[todoIndex].title = newTitle
            }
        }

        // Here we get the action we need
        const action = allActions[event]

        // Here we return a function with the actions we need,
        // but if we pass it to the child component via props,
        // then we need to type it again in as is done in utils.ts
        const wrapper: any = (...args: [any]) => {
            newTodos = [...todos]
            action(...args)
            updateTodos(newTodos)
        }
        return wrapper
    }
```

Comment: If I use `any`, Typescript won't make sense.

Comment: The only other way is to use `switch(event)` and return a function on each `case`.